# Can't figure out how to query a 2nd level resource in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble when querying Users.

My nesting resources are:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :photos do
      resources :pins
    end
  end
```

1.) I have a `user` model, that `has_many` `:photos`.

2.) `:photos has_many :pins`

I want to list my users on **which users have more pins in their photos**.

So, I tried:

```
@members_ordered = User.includes(photos: :pins).group("users.id").group("photos.id").group("pins.id").order('COUNT(pins.id) DESC')
```

Not working though. Any ideas? Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two observations, but neither directly fix the code in your example.

First, looking at my output from trying something similar, it seems like you either need quite complex SQL (which really isn't Rails' forte) or several simple queries (which, depending on the size of your app, could hit performance) to achieve this.

A little experimenting doesn't seem to show a significant difference (<1ms) in the time that one more complex query takes compared to that which three simple queries require (as in solution one)

**Solution one, if performance is not crucial**, for example, if this is a small, low-traffic solution, my instinct would be to add that the `User` model `has_many :pins, through: :photos`, which lets you call things like User.includes(photos: :pins).all, then `user.pins.count`, although, as I've mentioned, this causes a bit more database use.

**Solution two, if performance is important**, my suggestion would be to cache the count of pins against the user model. This could be as simple as an extra database column to store it, and have a background process (using delayed_job or similar) re-calculate the count each time it changes (so, maybe `after_create` in the `Pin` model.

The benefit of this is the slow, time-consuming query only gets run when the value changes, and the rest of the time, the value gets lifted from a single-table `SELECT`, which should take quite a bit less time than either solution one or the more complex query.

Both of these are less-than-perfect, and I think the most elegant and efficient way of working is to use a combination of a built-in function and a beautifully simple query:

**The third solution**, which brings together both of these options to some extent, is Rails' `counter_cache` option. As there are two levels to it, I can't see a native way to include all of these in one query, so we will automatically generate a count for each `Photo`, then add these up to get the User count.

1. Create a migration to add a pins_count field to the `Photo` model, so, in terminal, type;

   ```
   rails g migration AddPinsCountToPhotos pins_count:integer
   ```
2. Update the `belongs_to :photo` line of the `Pin` model to;

   ```
   belongs_to :photo, counter_cache: true
   ```

Now, every time a `Pin` gets created or deleted, the `pins_count` column of its `Photo` will be updated.

Now, to get the values for users;

1. Create a migration to add a pins_count field to the User model, so, in terminal, type;

   ```
   rails g migration AddPinsCountToUsers pins_count:integer
   ```
2. Now we need to create an method in the `Photo` model, which we will run each time a pin is saved, so add this to your `Photo` model;

   ```
   def update_user_counts
     total_photos = self.user.photos.sum(:pins_count)
     self.user.update_attribute(:pins_count, total_photos)
   end
   ```
3. Finally, we need to tell Rails to call this whenever a pin is created or updated. We do this with a simple method that just calls the action from the `Photo` model;

   ```
   after_save :update_photo_counts

   def update_photo_counts
     photo.update_user_counts
   end
   ```

Now, whenever a pin is saved, it automatically updates the `Photo`s `pins_count`, and then our new method totals the `pins_count`s from all of the `Photo`s for that user, and saves them to the `User`s `pins_count`

Comment: Hi @Matthew Higgins, so , I would try the first solution, is this what you mean?

scope :most_pins, -> {includes(photos: :pins).order('COUNT(pins)')}